# AAD Service to service with certificate JWT

Tags: php, azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

So, I've been reading these docs, implemented them and somehow I can't get through because Microsoft keeps nagging about an invalid signature

> Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains
>   an invalid signature.  [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of
>   key used by client: '7380XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  Please visit
>   'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' and query
>   for
>   'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/9a7exxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
>   to see configured keys]

My code:

```
function GUID()
{
    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
}

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/sub.xxxx.com/oauth2/token';
$apiId = '649952a2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'; // test
$identifierUrl = 'www.xxxx.com/test/OurClientName'; // test


$pvk = 'certificate.pvk';
$pub = file_get_contents('certificate.crt');

$fingerprint = base64_encode(pack('H*', openssl_x509_fingerprint($pub)));

$time = time();
$guid = GUID();

$signer = new \Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256();
$keychain = new \Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Keychain();
$token = (new \Lcobucci\JWT\Builder())
    ->setIssuer($apiId )
    ->setAudience($url)
    ->setHeader('x5t', $fingerprint)
    ->setId($guid, false)
    ->setIssuedAt($time)
    ->setNotBefore($time - 60)
    ->setExpiration($time + 60 * 60 * 12)
    ->set('sub', $apiId )
    ->sign($signer,  $keychain->getPrivateKey('file://'.$pvk))
    ->getToken();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $apiId,
    'client_assertion_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
    'client_assertion' => $token,
    'resource' => $identifierUrl
]);


$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($output));

curl_close($ch);
```

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials 
https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.2/README.md

Our service provider ensures me that the certificate with thumbprint 7380XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is installed in test and production and must work.

Debugging the JWT and validating it on jwt.io tells me that the signature is verified.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems that you need to upload the certificate to azure AD application.  Application->Settings ->Keys->upload public key

Comment: The service provider assures me that the certificate is active in AAD